# Stock daily graph using javascript and api source

Tags: javascript, html

Im doing a assignment where i use a stock api for data and then do a daily graph of the stock price. Not gonna do a live updating version but something from a previous day. My question is :

1.Where do i start?
  - i have no idea what resources to use and where to look for references
2.What resources to use?
  - It would be nice to have an idea what resources to use.

i already written a code to do a stock search and itll display data from alphavantage stock api. I need help doing the graphing part.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: do a google search on stock prices api
        Here are 5 free ones:
        Yahoo Finance
        Google Finance in Google Sheets
        IEX Cloud
        AlphaVantage
        World trading data
        Other APIs (Polygon.io, Intrinio, Quandl)

yahoo finance was discontinued but I'm told they brought it back last year.  IEX works pretty good.

Step 2: learn how the api works
        READ THE DOCS

step 3: determine from the api whether you need a charting lib.  chart.js is a free one 
        that might be what you need

step 4: design your program (pseudo code)